# Can Chern class determine nefness?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, chern-classes

Setting: $X$ is a compact complex manifold (not necessarily Kahler, not to mention projective), suppose $L_1$ and $L_2$ are two holomorphic line bundles on $X$. Now the Chern classes $c_1(L_1)=c_1(L_2)$, and $L_1$ is nef, can it imply $L_2$ also nef?

I believe the above claim is correct for $\partial\bar\partial$-manifold (compact complex manifolds satisfying $\partial\bar\partial$-lemma). For general compact complex manifold, is it correct or incorrect?

Comment: I'm not an expert, but from what I gather a line bundle is nef if all its restrictions to curves have nonnegative degree. That should only depend on the first chern class (since on a curve, the degree of a line bundle is obtained by pairing the first chern class with the fundamental homology class of the surface)

Comment: Dear @AchimKrause, thanks for your reply. But in a general compact manifold, there may doesn't exist any curve on it. As Demailly says in his book "Analytic method in AG", we define nef by the curvature condition, i.e., fix an  Hermitian  metric $\omega$, for every $\varepsilon> 0$, there exists a smooth metric $h_\varepsilon$ on $L$, such that $\sqrt \Theta_{h_\varepsilon}\geq {-\varepsilon\omega}$. In this more general case, can nefness still depend on the first chern class?

Comment: sorry, a typo in my reply...it should be $\sqrt{-1}\Theta_{h_\varepsilon}\geq-\varepsilon\omega$.

Comment: Ah sorry, I can now see how the definition of nef I looked up is only for projective varieties, and you explicitly exclude that case. Sorry! (as I said, not an expert)

Comment: Since the trivial bundle is always nef, it's equivalent to ask whether every line bundle with trivial Chern class is nef. Unless I'm very confused, the exponential exact sequence still exists in this setting, so such line bundles always arise from classes in $H^1 (X, \mathcal O_X)$. Can one express what condition on such a class gives nefness. Presumably if they lie in the image of $H^1(X, \mathbb R)$ that's sufficient, but maybe not necessary. I guess in this setting it may be easier to link it up to known counterexamples to Hodge theory for general manifolds.

Comment: In which cohomology group are you taking the equality $c_1(L_1)=c_1(L_2)$? If you assume this holds in Bott-Chern cohomology, then the answer to your question is yes, and is a simple exercise.

Comment: @YangMills, I assume they are equal in  Dolbeault cohomology. Yes, as you said, if it holds in Bott-Chern cohomology, the claim is also right. In fact, this is why I said the claim is always right for $\bar\partial\partial$-manifolds, in this case, when considering Dolbeault cohomology, the $\bar\partial\partial$-lemma plays an important role. So, when they are equal in  Dolbeault cohomology, is the claim still right?